# Powerpoint VBA - Slide Title Provided Instead of Presentation Name

Tags: vba, powerpoint

As part of a PowerPoint VBA macro to selectively copy slides from one presentation to another (source to destination), I observed a very strange behavior.  The act of pasting the slide in the destination appears to change the internal name of the destination presentation.

```
x$=ActiveWindow.Presentation.Name
```

Note:  At this point, debug shows the current presentation name in x$

```
ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides.Paste
x$=ActiveWindow.Presentation.Name
```

Now, x$ holds the title of the pasted slide.  It does not show as changed in the PowerPoint status bar (top of screen), but any VBA call to get the presentation name returns the slide title.  How is pasting a slide substituting the slide title into the presentation name?

It only does this for a particular presentation (first slide) so it's something in the source presentation.

Any ideas .... sounds like an actual error by PowerPoint.